# NFC on Samsung Galaxy Nexus raw MifareClassic authentication

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to use Android's NFC API to do raw authentication (send commands to MifareClassic cards using transceive method). But I keep getting TagLostException for all NfcA transceive calls.

This is my code:

```
NfcA mfa = NfcA.get(tagFromIntent);          
//MifareClassic mfa = MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent);
//IsoDep isodep = IsoDep.get(tagFromIntent);

mfa.connect();       
//manual authenticate
byte[] cmd = new byte[] {0x60, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00};               

try { 
    if(mfa.isConnected()) {
         byte[] result = mfa.transceive(cmd);
    }
} catch (TagLostException e) { 
    Log.i("mifaretest", "tag lost again!");
    throw e; 
} catch (IOException e) { 
    Log.i("mifaretest", "IOException!");
    // No need to deal with, will return false anyway 
} 

mfa.close();
```

As Google document indicates that: Applications must not append the EoD (CRC) to the payload, it will be automatically calculated. I leave the last two bytes empty.
I also tried the following commands:
`byte[] cmd = new byte[] {0x60, 0x04};`  or
`byte[] cmd = new byte[] {0x60, 0x04, 0xD1, 0x3D};`

All of them throw TagLostException.
Any insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Android adds the CRC to the payload of the transceive parameter, so when you send `{0x60, 0x04}`, Android will add the corresponding 2 CRC bytes before sending it off to the card. However, that is only one half of the story. Android will also inspect the response from the card. It will check the CRC on the response and strip it off. If the CRC on the response is incorrect, it will throw an exception instead.

Now have a look at section 11.1 of the [MIFARE CLassic datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S50YYX.pdf). You can see that the card response does not contain a CRC in this case, so it will be rejected by Android and an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Does that mean raw command Transceive will not work for Android + MifareClassic?

Comment: Is there anyway to work around this Android restriction? Android is using libnfc-nxp, is it possible that I build a modified version of the library (maybe using a different name) and use Android NDK to load that library? In which that response crc is not checked? And I don't want to root my device.

Comment: Without rooting your device, there is nothing you can do. The restriction is not in libnfc-nxp, I think, but in Android's NFC manager. You could build a modified firmware to change this behaviour. However, if you go down this route, I expect you will probably encounter other restrictions, both in libnfc-nxp and in the NFC hardware. They are both meant to handle MIFARE communication automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is this restriction only on Mifare Classic? If I use a different NFC tag (Mifare Desfire or Mifare Plus for example), can I work around this restriction? Or do you know any other brand tags that can work with the raw authentication using the transceive method Android provided? Provided that the tag has authentication built in.

Comment: MIFARE DESfire is fully supported. You use normal `IsoDep.transceive()`. MIFARE Plus is fully supported, too, by `IsoDep` if it is configured to the highest Security Level.

Answer (score 1):

IsoDep class has its timeout which can be read and changed.

For high demanding cryptographical operations you should definitly change it,since default value is something like 300 miliseconds.